# How override i18n for inherited property?

Tags: java, internationalization, alfresco

Let say that there is a type which extended from another one:

```
<type name="sc:myType">
    <parent>bpm:workflowTask</parent>
    <properties>
        <property name="sc:myProperty">
            <type>d:text</type>
        </property>
    </properties>
</type>
```

i18n for `sc:myProperty` looks like that:

```
sc_myModel.property.sc_myProperty.title=Description
```

But what if it is needed to override `cm:title` for `sc:myType`? How to do that **without** overriding `cm:title` for all types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that is better to provide a `label-id` attribute in [field](https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-5408-forms#field) tag and specify custome message.

```
<field label-id="some.message" id="cm:title">
```